# How do I use the & operator in java? porting C code

Tags: java, c++, c, bitwise-operators

So I've got this simple code in C.

```
 if (flags & 4)
```

Now when I port the line to java:

```
 if ((flags & 4) == 1)
```

It doesn't trigger. Whats the correct way to port the C code to Java? What am I doing wrong with the & operator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be `!= 0` rather than `== 1`:

```
if ((flags & 4) != 0)
```

The reason for this is that in C anything that is not zero is considered `true` in an `if` statement, while Java forces you to use Booleans. In this case, the expression can evaluate either to 4 or to 0, so comparing it with 1 is always false.

Answer (score 8):

`if ((flags & 4)==4)`

When you use bitwise and to "mask" all the bits except one, the result isn't going to be one, it's going to be the bit you checked for.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
if ((flags & 4) != 0)
```

`== 1` will not work even in C